# vue.config.js in Vue CLI, what else is there to change other than configureWebpack?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-4

I'm new to the Vue CLI ecosystem. In vue.config.js (@vue/cli 4.5.9), other than `configureWebpack`, what is commonly changed inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [v4.5.9 docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) specify all available options (other than `configureWebpack`) that can be configured:

- [`baseUrl`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl)
- [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)
- [`outputDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir)
- [`assetsDir`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir)
- [`indexPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#indexpath)
- [`filenameHashing`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing)
- [`pages`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages)
- [`lintOnSave`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#lintonsave)
- [`runtimeCompiler`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler)
- [`transpileDependencies`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#transpiledependencies)
- [`productionSourceMap`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap)
- [`crossorigin`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#crossorigin)
- [`integrity`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#integrity)
- [`chainWebpack`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack)
- [`css.modules`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-modules)
- [`css.requireModuleExtension`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-requiremoduleextension)
- [`css.extract`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract)
- [`css.sourceMap`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-sourcemap)
- [`css.loaderOptions`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-loaderoptions)
- [`devServer`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)
- [`devServer.proxy`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy)
- [`parallel`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#parallel)
- [`pwa`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pwa)
- [`pluginOptions`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pluginoptions)